# How to assign an array element value to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From a select query I get a 3 elements array. The only way I found to assign each element of the array to individual variables was by repeating 3 times the select and using the fetchcolum(n=0, 1, 2) function.
Is there a more elegant way? I tried with fetchAll() but was unable to extract the individual values.
I know that this type of issue has already been adressed many times, but either the cases are too peculiar or too advanced for me. The array object is really a nightmare.

```
<?php
$pdo->query("create table t (D int, M int, Y int)");
$pdo->query("insert into t (D , M , Y ) values (30, 7, 2022)");

$sql = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT `D`, `M`,`Y`
FROM `t` ");
$sql->execute([]);
$Cur_Date = $sql->fetchColumn(0);
print_r ($Cur_Date);
$Day = $Cur_Date;
echo $Day;
            
$sql = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT `D`, `M`,`Y`
FROM `t` ");
$sql->execute([]);
$Cur_Date = $sql->fetchColumn(1);
print_r ($Cur_Date);
$Month = $Cur_Date;
echo $Month;

$sql = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT `D`, `M`,`Y`
FROM `t` ");
$sql->execute([]);
$Cur_Date = $sql->fetchColumn(2);
print_r ($Cur_Date);
$Year = $Cur_Date;
echo $Year;
```

Comment: `unable to extract the individual values`...because? fetchAll() will return a list of all the rows retrieved by the query. Loop through the rows, then for each row you can get all the columns, each one individually if you want. It's just regular usage of PHP arrays - nothing special. Please show what you tried and explain what went wrong. The version you've showed above is highly inefficient and doesn't really make any sense to do it that way - it's clearly an X-Y problem (i.e. you didn't know how to do something, so instead of solving it you tried to invent a bizarre workaround).

Comment: Or if you only ever expect one row returned, just use fetch() to get a single row at a time. Again, you can then access each field within it simply by its name.

Comment: P.S. I know this is probably just an example, but if you intend to use any of this for real, please don't store date values in separate columns like this. the `date` and `datetime` column types exist for a reason...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was quite aware of the inefficiency (or amateurism) of my version due to a lack of understanding of the array field. (I am of the old school when a 2 dimension table element was accessible by its (i,j) indices). That's why I posted my question. CFulford proposed the elegant solution that you mentioned.

Comment: About your PS warning: I use extensively DATETIME attributes in my project, but my example is adressing a very peculiar issue abour parsing names of some external files. Thanks.

Comment: I see. A named index is really no different to a numbered index when you come to think about it - both are just identifiers for the location :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is the fetch method.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

I would also look into the different fetch flags (the mode parameter in the docs).
Specifically FETCH_ASSOC.
Calling fetch with this as the flag returns an associative array where the array keys are the column names.

It should make your code much simpler.

```
<?php
$pdo->query("create table t (D int, M int, Y int)");
$pdo->query("insert into t (D , M , Y ) values (30, 7, 2022)");

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `D`, `M`,`Y` FROM `t`");
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$Day = $row['D'];
$Month = $row['M'];
$Year = $row['Y'];
```

Comment: I tested it successfully. Thanks a lot. My interpretation is that the array created by the fectch action and the appropriate parameter, is a 1 row x 3 column table which elements are accessed by the column "name" (or key in more appropriate language). Am I right?

Comment: Basically, yes.
Note that fetch only returns 1 array at a time so for results with more than 1 row you would need to either call fetch multiple times or use fetchAll.